# Laravel One to Many relation doesn't work as intended?

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, relation

I have a big problem. I have a Model containing a foreign key on "another model".

My first Model is a `user` and my second model is `project`. A User can have many Projects and a Project belongs to exactly one User. Since I have this kind of relation, I do store the reference inside my `project`-Model inside the column `user`.

```
class Project extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user');
    }
}
```

According to the docs, I should be able to get the properties of my User-Model using `$project->user->name`but when I do a var_dump on `$project`, I only get the user ID, I've stored inside my projects-table instead of an User-Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention

In user model

```
public function projects()
{   

    return $this->hasMany('App\projects);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so basicallyI missed the part with "you have to define it in both models". stupid me.